# How to implement multimap_agg in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

Can anyone help in providing the solution how multimap_agg in SQL can be used in spark sql

Comment: post the code what you have tried. Also update question with some sample data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.